# Laravel localisation - database content

Tags: laravel, localization

I'm looking at frameworks and CMSs for a project we are starting, a website that needs to support localised content.

Laravel looks good and certainly allows you to localise UI content, but it doesn't seem to natively support the localisation of content stored in a database. This seems surprising, I'm wondering if I'm overlooking something? (CakePHP, for example, has a TranslateBehavior for this purpose).

**Edit** To be clear, I'm asking if there's anything baked into Laravel to handle this, I'm aware I could code equivalent functionality but think that that would be a fair amount of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your data as it enters or leaves the database is fairly easy.

If you store the translation key in the database, you can translate when you pull the data out. Use [getter and setter methods in the model](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators).  You may also want to look at [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events).

Comment: Thanks for replying - do you mean manually create extra fields (one per field per language) and then manually handle these when reading from/writing to the database etc? If so, I was asking if there's anything built in, so as to avoid all of these. I'll update my question.